# Какой родительный падеж у мн. ч. фамилии Регниц?

Tags: падежи, окончания, склонение-фамилий

Например, «Регницов нет дома» (как «[Ференцов](https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Ferents/skloneniye.html)»)?

Почему-то, не знаю почему, окончание -ов подрезывает слух. Но если найдётся пример или правило, подтверждающее его правильность, то пускай.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно склонять по типу склонения фамилии *Лейбниц*:

именительный (кто?) Лейбниц/Лейбницы;

родительный (кого?) Лейбница/Лейбницов;

дательный (кому?) Лейбницу/Лейбницам;

винительный (кого?) Лейбница/Лейбницов;

творительный (кем?) Лейбницом/Лейбницами;

предложный (о ком?) Лейбнице/Лейбницах.

https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Leybnits/skloneniye.html?ysclid=l6xgrykt48476831232